# "covered in lumps" vs "covered with lumps"

Tags: prepositions

Definitions of "lumpy" are as follows:

in [Oxford dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/lumpy?q=lumpy%20),

> full of lumps; covered **in** lumps

in [Webster's dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lumpy),

> filled or covered **with** lumps

I wonder if there is any difference.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60805/covered-with-vs-covered-in-vs-covered-by)

Comment: @ColinFine Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is really no difference in this case. "Covered" implies we are speaking about something that happens at a surface, so "covered in" and "covered with" have much the same meaning.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you look carefully at the definitions, you will see that they both describe two situations:

- there are lumps inside something: for example, when you make bread and don't mix it sufficiently,there will be hard pieces (lumps) throughout the bread.
- there are lumps on the surface of something: for example, if you paint a wall and don't spread the paint evenly.

The Oxford dictionary uses two sencences, because they chose to use the preposition "in", which can only be used about lumps on the surface.

The Webster's dictionary has a single-sentence definition, because uses the preposition "with". The phrase "filled with" describes lumps inside something, and "covered with" describes lumps on the surface.

To sum up, "covered in" can only be used about surface lumps, but "covered with" and "filled with" can be used to describe surface and internal lumps respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much.